# Passing an associative array from Java to PHP

Tags: php, android, arrays, soap

I am trying to pass an associative array from Java to PHP. I am getting "Can not serialize Exception."

The backend php code(soap call) is like this:

```
function getTrips($data)
{ 
     foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
      ...
    }  
}
```

I am making java client call like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> Data = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Data.put("start_date", dateFormat.format(date));
        Data.put("end_date", dateFormat.format(date));
        Data.put("loc", "1");

        request.addProperty("data",Data );

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

I tried with NameValuePair code is like this:

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start_date", dateFormat.format(date)));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("end_date", dateFormat.format(date)));
request.addProperty("data",nameValuePairs );
```

Comment: Did you try NameValuePair instead of HashMap?

Comment: @Nizam ya i tried  still same exception

Comment: @savari: Did u fix this issue. I am also getting the same issue?